# Capistrano 3 + Sprockets 3 + Rails 4.2.1 won't deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, capistrano3

I ran `bundle update` and updated `sprockets` to 3.0.0.

When I try to deploy via Capistrano 3 I get the following error:

```
INFO [e54ac5ca] Running /usr/bin/env cp /var/www/testapp/releases/20150414002210/public/assets/manifest* /var/www/testapp/releases/20150414002210/assets_manifest_backup as deploy@xx.xxx.xxx.xx
DEBUG [e54ac5ca] Command: cd /var/www/testapp/releases/20150414002210 && /usr/bin/env cp /var/www/testapp/releases/20150414002210/public/assets/manifest* /var/www/testapp/releases/20150414002210/assets_manifest_backup
DEBUG [e54ac5ca]    cp: cannot stat ‘/var/www/testapp/releases/20150414002210/public/assets/manifest*’
DEBUG [e54ac5ca]    : No such file or directory
DEBUG [d2c5a990]    cp: cannot stat ‘/var/www/testapp/releases/20150414002210/public/assets/manifest*’
DEBUG [d2c5a990]    : No such file or directory
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx: cp exit status: 1
cp stdout: Nothing written
cp stderr: cp: cannot stat ‘/var/www/testapp/releases/20150414002210/public/assets/manifest*’: No such file or directory
/Users/HomeHome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:16:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/HomeHome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
SSHKit::Command::Failed: cp exit status: 1
cp stdout: Nothing written
cp stderr: cp: cannot stat ‘/var/www/testapp/releases/20150414002210/public/assets/manifest*’: No such file or directory
/Users/HomeHome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:95:in `exit_status='
/Users/HomeHome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:179:in `block in _execute'
/Users/HomeHome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `tap'
/Users/HomeHome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `_execute'
/Users/HomeHome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/HomeHome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:68:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/HomeHome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:77:in `within'
/Users/HomeHome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:67:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/HomeHome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Users/HomeHome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Users/HomeHome/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:backup_manifest
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx: cp exit status: 1
cp stdout: Nothing written
cp stderr: cp: cannot stat ‘/var/www/testapp/releases/20150414002210/public/assets/manifest*’: No such file or directory
```

I've looked all around for people possibly having the same issues and it seems there are no issues or comments on it anywhere...

Honestly I'm not even sure how `sprockets`, `sprockets-rails` are related to rails. It's all quite confusing to me... for example, the default `Gemfile` which comes with a fresh `Rails 4.2.1` app says sprockets 3.0.0 is allowed in `Gemfile.lock`, yet when you go to the sprockets 2->3 upgrade guide, it shows that `//= include` has been removed, yet it's right there in the `application.js` file.

So, maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not quite sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is easy to fix, but I think that first we should address some of the other questions.

`sprockets` is a ruby library that automates managing web front end assets (CSS, JS, images, etc).

It is based on the idea of keeping your asset files *logically organized* in development, and to then *chain and minify* them before deploying to production. Sprockets makes this process automatic.

Rails 3.1 (a long time ago, now) released a new feature called "Asset Pipeline", that automated the management of web assets. The Rails' Asset Pipeline was, and still is, powered by `sprockets`.

Both `sprockets` and `rails` are actively maintained and developed libraries. New versions are released with new features and breaking changes.
I believe that Rails does not use, by default, the latest version of `sprockets`. It is ok, we're talking about compiling CSS and JS here, not interacting with some external API; even an old version of `sprockets` can do the job.
This means that updating `sprockets` is not a good idea. Each version of Rails declares a specific (min-max) version of `sprockets`, for good reason: it's the version that the current Asset Pipeline relies on. Updating it might break things.

Then, let's move to the manifest file.
By default, after *precompiling* the assets (resolving references, including some files into others, chaining and minifying them), the compiled assets are copied in `RAILS_ROOT/public/assets`. With them, Rails generates a `manifest` file that contains a list of all the precompiled assets. In your version of Rails it should be `manifest.json`, but it used to be `manifest.yml`.

Now, the last piece of the puzzle is `capistrano`, which I imagine you know how to use.

The line:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/var/www/testapp/releases/20150414002210/public/assets/manifest*’
```

means that `capistrano` tried to find a `manifest` file in your `RAILS_ROOT/public/assets` directory. The wildcard is there because it might be either `manifest.json` or `manifest.yml`, depending on the version of Rails.
Also, `stat` means that `capistrano` is trying to get some info from the file, probably to figure out how recent it is.

The problem is that the file is not present.
You should [precompile the assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets), then **commit the generated files** and try to deploy again.

Comment: Actually you don't need to precompile the assets locally and commit them to repository afterwards. It's a bug, and capistrano-rails guys are working on it right now: https://github.com/capistrano/rails/pull/112 & https://github.com/capistrano/rails/issues/111

anyway, thumbs up for a such detailed answer!

Comment: Oh, nice info, thanks. When deploying with capistrano, I always prefer a deploy strategy that uses a _deploy branch_, so that the "compiled assets commits" will not pollute your _master_. Also, more often than not you'll be  deploying to a cluster of servers, and I find it inefficient to compile them again and again on each server you deploy to. Also, precompiling them locally makes it easier to automate (within the cap deploy task) uploading them to a CDN.

Comment: To expand on the comment from @mid, what happened is that sprocket 3.0.0 [introduced a change](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/commit/ce6508e8540f829c6221afa39fdf718e4dded096) where it renamed the manifest file from manifest.json to .sprockets-manifest.json.  We are in the process of updating capistrano-rails to check for both file names and use whichever one it finds.

Comment: @IsaacBetesh Thank you for that information. I had been wracking my brain as to why manifest.json was not getting created, and didn't think to do an `ls -a` to see the new hidden file!

Comment: A simple `bundle update` that bumped rails from 4.2.3 to 4.2.4, capistrano from 3.2.1 to 3.4.0 and capistrano-rails from 1.1.2 to 1.1.3 did the trick for me.

Answer (score 22):

If you are using `capistrano-rails`, try update to `1.1.3`. This has fixed the issue for me.

[capistrano-rails CHANGELOG:](https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

```
1.1.3 (Apr 18 2015)
- Fixed no_release behaviour (https://github.com/capistrano/rails/pull/95)
- Allow assets manifest backup with folder "manifests" (https://github.com/capistrano/rails/pull/92)
- Handle Sprocket 3 manifest filename
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! for otherr dummies like me - in gemfile set version directly gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.3'

Answer (score 4):

per comment, I fixed this by upgrading capistrano-rails from `1.1.2 -> 1.1.3`

```
# Gemfile
'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.3'
```