# Rails capistrano deployment failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, capistrano

I'm new Ruby on Rails (ROR) developer. I tried to deploy my app but it fails with this error:

> cd /var/www/sa/releases/20170325010355 && /usr/bin/env cp /etc/profile.d/lang.sh: line 19: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot
>   change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory 
>   /var/www/sa/releases/20170325010355/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-3f843658ebd0a7e65891643e86a5bb23.json
>   /var/www/sa/releases/20170325010355/assets_manifest_backup'
>       cp stderr: Nothing written

I've read [this](https://github.com/capistrano/rails/issues/111) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617239/capistrano-3-sprockets-3-rails-4-2-1-wont-deploy) article and I've tried to fix as per the articles but I had no success.  Any ideas?

My gems versions:

```
sprockets (3.7.1)
sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
capistrano-rails (1.2.3, 1.1.8) 
Rails 5.0.2
ruby 2.4.1
capistrano (3.8.0)
```